# Asp.net MVC Booked StartDate and EndDate check

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I wanted to check if my first reservation
res2.StartDate and res2.EndDate are not the same of my res1.StartDate and res1.EndDate of a specific room.
And also not in the between period of res1.StartDate and res1.EndDate so I can book the room.

I have done this

```
var result = from r in _reservationData.GetAll()
             .Where(r => r.RoomId == reservation.RoomId)
             .Where(r => r.StartDate == reservation.StartDate)
             .Where(r => r.EndDate == reservation.EndDate)
                     orderby r.StartDate
                     select r;
```

But this is checking if they are equal only. How can I check if the reservation2 period not in the between of the reservation1 period??

Thank you in advance.

This is un update:

```
private bool CheckIfThisRoomIsAvailable(Reservation reservation)
    {
        // return the room data
        var result3 = _roomData.GetById(reservation.RoomId);

        // return the reservations of this room and 
        // check if the startdate of the new reservation
        // is greater than the enddate of the old reservation
        var result1 = from r in _reservationData.GetAll()
            .Where(r => (r.RoomId == reservation.RoomId)
             && !(r.EndDate < reservation.StartDate))
                      select r;

        /* return the reservations of this room and check if the startdate  
         of the new reservation less than the enddate of old reservation
         and check if the enddate of the new reservation is less than 
         the startdate of the old reservation
        */
        var result2 = from r in _reservationData.GetAll()
             .Where(r => (r.RoomId == reservation.RoomId)
              && !(r.EndDate > reservation.StartDate)
              && !(r.StartDate > reservation.EndDate))
                      select r;

        // checking condtions
        if (!result3.Status.Contains("Available"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        else if (result1 is null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else if (result2 is null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        { return false; }
    }
```

But the problem is with if condition, the result1 or 2 is null, it returns false??

Comment: Check if the roomid is the same and then does `reservation.StartDate` fall on or in between the start/end of any existing reservation *or* does `reservation.EndDate` fall on or in between the start/end of any existing reservation. Use the greater than and less than symbols for this.

Comment: I am also assuming this is code that will never be put into production (ie. homework). If that is not the case you need to also work in how timezones work with scheduling. Think of requests coming from outside the server timezone as well as what happens when a timezone is updated (example daylight savings being abolished in some time zone in the very near future that uses your system and there are future reservations).

Comment: Yes This is an assignment not for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this condition:

```
var canIBookTheRoom =
            !_reservationData.GetAll()
            .Where(r => r.RoomId == reservation.RoomId)
            .Where(r => (r.StartDate <= reservation.EndDate)
                && (r.EndDate >= reservation.StartDate)).ToList().Any();

        // checking condtions
        if (!result3.Status.Contains("Available"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (canIBookTheRoom) 
        { return true; }
        else return false;
```

I hope this help anyone!